# Strange behavior of a MacOs app created with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I've created a PyQt Mac app  with pyinstaller.
When the app is launched, the app icon appears briefly in the dock, then disappears as if the application was closed and then reappears a few seconds later.
The application seems to work as expected.
I also have checked the processes and I've found that 2 processes were launched and one them was stalled (see below screen capture).

Is it the normal behavior of a Pyinstaller packaged app?
Is there a way to correct this behavior?

[image]

Comment: If you have packaged your app with `--onefile`/`-F` mode, then it could be possible that the initial process (that briefly appears) is the part where all the package contents are unpacked into a temporary directory before the final application launch. The only way to correct it would be to use the `--onedir` mode, which creates a package directory with uncompressed files.

Comment: You got it! 
thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have packaged your app with `--onefile`/`-F` mode, the initial process (that briefly appears) is the part where all the package contents are unpacked into a temporary directory before the final application launch. The only way to correct it would be to use the `--onedir` mode, which creates a package directory with uncompressed files.

This has been documented in [How the One-File Program Works](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works) section

> The bootloader uncompresses the support files and writes copies into the the temporary folder. This can take a little time. That is why a one-file app is a little slower to start than a one-folder app.